# DAO ETH account thru Shapeshift

Tags: dao, shapeshift

In 2016 I did exactly the sentence below. Not ETH account was ever sent to me. Now I have almost 10 ETH sitting on the DAO that I can’t access. I tried customer support for both ShapeShift and myethwallet:

> “If you don’t already have an ETH account, you can have daohub.org
> create you one right on the website, select the ShapeShift option,
> choose that you don’t have an account and it will generate you one on
> the fly using myetherwallet. Then you can insert that account address
> and and use the shifty button popup to send to the DAO!”

I can see ShapeShift taking in my BTC from my Circle Wallet but then they withdraw to some ETH account that then took the DAO token. See below is my transaction.

Order Summary:

- Order Number: 35dc095a7b
- You Deposited: 0.3 BTC
- You Received: 9.64040070 ETH
- The exchange took 16 seconds
- Deposit Address: `1BjnVzWLqC4hq5ph9CkCnkHWVEnwVs9AyN`
- Withdraw Address: `0x0e257ca1ff6457c5c3d39a27f0adeb1fbb1b9350`
- Transaction Hash: `0x620ff746ac662dfefcb116ae1a64f3b36fb6a709e4fd95bbd7a3548c4da1e0b1`

I NEVER RECEIVED ANY INFORMATION OTHER THEN THIS. My money is in the DAO now. I see it on the `0x0e257ca1ff6457c5c3d39a27f0adeb1fbb1b9350` address but I have no idea what the username and password for the Ethernet wallet they created!

Please help.

Comment: Do you remember the exact page where you purchased from? Shapeshift was an exchange I don't remember them providing wallet services. Although it is possible that a third party did it using their services for the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

So you directed Shapeshift to send the funds to 0x0e257ca1ff6457c5c3d39a27f0adeb1fbb1b9350 correct? I see the ERC20 tokens in your wallet. You have lost access to this wallet?

If you haven't lost the private keys to this wallet address then you should should be able to retrieve the tokens.

There isn't any ETH in this wallet to use as gas to move these tokens. If you still have access to this wallet, you would need to send some ETH first to move those tokens out of there.

Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi ...thank for replying.  Obviously as ETH going up, my frustration is proportional going up lol.   So...shapeshift tells me they never created an account/wallet.  All they did was process a transaction.  What is weird is on that exact day, I did save an MyEtherWallet account and I can access it, BUT,... if doesn't have the 0x0e257ca1ff6457c5c3d39a27f0adeb1fbb1b9350  address in it.  It has a different address.   Could it be that the wallet had multiple address and I just can't load it in since shapeshifter did it/